# Converting strings to floats

Tags: perl

could soemone help me with the following condition, please?
I'm trying to compare $price and $lsec.

```
if( (sprintf("%.2f", ($price*100+0.5)/100)*1 != $lsec*1) )
{
                print Dumper($price,$lsec)
}
```

Sometimes the dumper prints same numbers(as strings) and jumps in.
Thought, that multiplying with 1 makes  floats from them...

Here dumper output:

```
$VAR1 = '8.5';
$VAR2 = '8.5';
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you,

Greetings and happy easter.

Comment: `$price*100+0.5` will probably not do what you expect, if you expect rounding to occur. With `$price = 8.5` that part of the equation will yield `850.5`.

Comment: Run `perl -e 'printf "%.2f",8.505'` to see what you are doing wrong.

Comment: You're dumping `$price` and `$lsec`, but those aren't the numbers you are comparing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct to say that multiplying a string by 1 will force it to be evaluated as a number, but the numeric `!=` comparator will do the same thing. This is presumably a technique you have acquired from other languages as Perl will generally do the *right thing* and there is no need to force a cast of either operand.

Lets take a look at the values you're comparing:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my $price = '8.5';
my $lsec = '8.5';

my $rounded_price = sprintf("%.2f", ($price * 100 + 0.5) / 100);
print "$rounded_price <=> $lsec\n";

if ( $rounded_price != $lsec ) {
  print Dumper($price,$lsec);
}
```

**output**

```
8.51 <=> 8.5
$VAR1 = '8.5';
$VAR2 = '8.5';
```

So Perl is correctly saying that 8.51 is unequal to 8.5.

I suspect that your

```
($price * 100 + 0.5) / 100
```

is intended to round `$price` to two decimal places, but all it does in fact is to increase `$price` by 0.005. I think you meant to write

```
int($price * 100 + 0.5) / 100
```

but you also put the value through `sprintf` which is another way to do the same thing.

*Either*

```
$price = int($price * 100 + 0.5) / 100
```

*or*

```
$price = sprintf ".2f", $price
```

but both is overkill!

Comment: When you have complication code inside a conditional, it's hard to see what's going on. The best part of Borodin's answer is the clean code that elucidates the problem.

Answer (score 5):

There is a difference between what is *stored* in a Perl variable and how it is *used*. You are correct that multiplying by 1 forces a variable to be *used* as a number. It also causes the number to be stored in the [`SV`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlguts.html#Datatypes) data structure that represents the variable to the interpreter. You can use the [`Devel::Peek`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Devel/Peek.html) module to see what Perl has stored in each variable:

```
use Devel::Peek;
my $num = "8.5";
Dump $num;
```

outputs:

```
SV = PV(0xa0a46d8) at 0xa0c3f08
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (POK,pPOK)
  PV = 0xa0be8c8 "8.5"\0
  CUR = 3
  LEN = 4
```

continuing...

```
my $newnum = $num * 1;
Dump $num;
Dump $newnum;
```

outputs:

```
SV = PVNV(0xa0a46d8) at 0xa0c3f08
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADMY,NOK,POK,pIOK,pNOK,pPOK)
  IV = 8
  NV = 8.5
  PV = 0xa0be8c8 "8.5"\0
  CUR = 3
  LEN = 4
SV = NV(0x9523660) at 0x950df20
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADMY,NOK,pNOK)
  NV = 8.5
```

The attributes we are concerned with are `PV` (string pointer), `NV` (floating-point number), and `IV` (integer). Initially, `$num` only has the string value, but using it as a number (e.g. in multiplication) causes it to store the numeric values. However, `$num` still "remembers" that it is a string, which is why `Data::Dumper` treats it like one.

For most purposes, there is no need to *explicitly* force the use of a string as a number, since operators and functions can use them in the most appropriate form. The `==` and `!=` operators, for example, coerce their operands into numeric form to do numeric comparison. Using `eq` or `ne` instead forces a string comparison. This is one more reason to always [`use warnings`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) in your Perl scripts, since trying to compare a non-numeric string with `==` will garner this warning:

```
Argument "asdf" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) at -e line 1.
```

Comment: Add this to Borodin's answer and you pretty much have the whole story. :)

Comment: So I have an example where Data::Dumper is storing my value as a string, but letting me do arithmetic on it.  If JSON::PP were not so picky about quoting everything, I'd be ok.  So how does one force the storage of a scalar into a number?  *1 and +1 have not worked for me yet.

Answer (score 1):

This part:

```
($price*100+0.5)/100)
```

If you put in 8.5, you get back 8.505. Which naturally is not equal to 8.5. Since you do not change `$price`, you do not notice any difference.

Perl handles conversion automatically, so you do not need to worry about that.

```
my $x = "8.5";
my $y = 8.5;
print "Equal" if $x == $y; # Succeeds
```

The nature of the comparison, `==` or in your case `!=` converts the arguments to numeric, whether they are numeric or not.

Answer (score -3):

You're doing nothing wrong. Perl converts it to a string before dumping it. For comparisons, use `==` and `!=` for numeric comparisons and `eq` and `ne` for a string comparisons. Perl converts to strings and numbers as needed.

Example:

`$ perl -MData::Dumper -e "my $a=3.1415; print Dumper($a);"`

`$VAR1 = '3.1415';`

Comment: You haven't explained the problem - that 8.5 is apparently unequal to 8.5

Comment: Well, the wrong part is not realizing that floating point math using limited precision is often a bit fuzzy.